# Defining a Chebyshev series expansion

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I'm trying to implement the Clenshaw algorithm for a truncated Chebyshev series. I think I've grasped the algorithm itself, but I'm a bit confused by an additional term in the definition.

I have found a definition of the partial sum of a Chebyshev expansion as follows:

$$S_N(x) = \frac{1}{2}c_0 + \sum^N_{k=1}c_kT_k(x)$$

The source I'm reading (a sample chapter of "Numerical Methods for Special Functions" - Gil/Segura/Temme) defines the sum in vector form as:

$$\widetilde{S}_N(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}c_kT_k(x) = \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{t} $$

Using this latter equation alone I'm able to follow the derivation, until the author(s) convert from $\widetilde{S}_N$ back to $S_N$ according to:

$$ S_N = \widetilde{S}_N - \frac{1}{2}c_0$$

Could somebody explain where the $\frac{1}{2}c_0$ term comes from? I don't understand why a series involving orthogonal polynomials should require such a term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple manipulation using the fact $T_0(x)=1$:
$$\widetilde{S}_N(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}c_kT_k(x)
=\left(\frac{1}{2}c_0 + \frac{1}{2}c_0\right)T_0(x) + \sum_{k=1}^{N}c_kT_k(x)\\
=\frac{1}{2}c_0 + \left(\frac{1}{2}c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{N}c_kT_k(x)\right)
=\frac{1}{2}c_0 + S_N(x)
$$
Note: If you define $S_N$ using $c_0/2$, this has the advantage of having **uniform** formulas for actually computing the Chebyshev expansion using the orthogonality relations.
(See e.g. the special cases $n=m=0$ with the factor 2 for the continous and discrete relations  in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Orthogonality) article.)

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Are you able to explain the motivation behind the definition of the $S_N$ term?

Comment: @Speedy: See the editing answer.